# Multiplying Tensor with Lazy Tensor

Tags: pytorch, gaussian, knn, gaussian-mixture-model

[image]

I am trying to compute KNN neighbours with Mahalanobis distance instead of L1 or L2 norm

[image]

I am getting the error of multiplying Tensor with Lazy Tensor.
[image]

Any ideas how solve this problem using Lazy tensors or gpu libaries which already solve this ?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Done

Comment: I have no experience with LazyTensors. The error suggests that torch.matmul doesnt take as arguments LazyTensors. You can either:
- convert your LazyTensor to Tensor or 
- use a matrix product function that supports LazyTensors.